# jQuery Slidertron link to a slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Hi all I'm using [jQuery Slidertron](http://caesoft.es/js/jquery.slidertron-1.1/docs/index.html) as essentially a page turner. It is built in to a template I am using and I really like the look of it, but I wonder if it is possible to link to specific slides.
For example, I want a button to jump to the second slide in my reel regardless of which slide is active.

Is this possible?

If not that, maybe I could initiate the navigation action a certain number of times behind the scenes to use navFirstSelector back to slide one, then turn a certain number of pages?

Here is an example implementation

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.slidertron-1.1.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->

<style type="text/css">
    #slider {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
    }
    #slider .viewer {
        width: 500px;
        height: 375px;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
    #slider .viewer .reel {
        display: none;
        height: 375px;
    }
    #slider .viewer .reel .slide {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 375px;
    }
 </style>

<!-- HTML -->

<div id="slider">
     <div class="viewer">
        <div class="reel">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<!-- JS -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider').slidertron({
        viewerSelector: '.viewer',
        reelSelector: '.viewer .reel',
        slidesSelector: '.viewer .reel .slide',
        advanceDelay: 3000,
        speed: 'slow'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your plugin with `indicatorSelector: '.indicator ul li'`

```
$('#slider').slidertron({
    viewerSelector: '.viewer',
    reelSelector: '.viewer .reel',
    slidesSelector: '.viewer .reel .slide',
    advanceDelay: 3000,
    speed: 'slow',
    indicatorSelector: '.indicator ul li' // Newly added line
});
```

then hide it with css (only if you dont want to show this navigation dots)

```
.indicator{
    display:none !important;
}
```

then run the following command

```
$('.indicator li').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

here `eq()` takes image index as a parameter (starts with 0. just like an array index);

so if you want to go to 3rd slide then use

```
$('.indicator li').eq(2).trigger('click');
```